# LogParser for Apache like Microsoft IIS LogParser

Tags: apache-2.2, logparser

Is there a tool for Apache comparable to Microsoft's II LogParser?

Comment: You don't mention whether your Apache build is under Windows/Linux/Unix/OS X etc... That might narrow down the suggestions to those most suited for your application.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have not "a comparable", but "the same" LogParser with the same syntax, then use the very same [**MS LogParser 2.2**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) against the Apache logs. It works just the same... And it doesn't need 'installation' -- works directly from an USB stick too.

BTW, said MS LogParser is not a specific *IIS* LogParser. It also parses all kinds of logfiles, it parses the Windows Registry, Active Directory objects, the Windows eventlogs, generic XML/CSV/TSV formatted text files (FTP, Firewall, SMTP, Exchange, ... logs), Network Monitor capture (.cap) files, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more free-softwarey, [analog](http://www.analog.cx/) is very fast and very, very good.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).  I can't comment on it's similarity to the Microsoft tool, though. (So I probably shouldn't even post this answer.)